# Should .jest directory be gitignored?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Hey guys I have a project running jest and enzyme in react native and I'm wondering if the directory `.jest` should be gitignored?

Answer (score -2):

Folders are normally gitignored when their content is generated dynamically or it is compiled.

Comment: I feel like the second half of this answer is, "and .jest is dynamically generated."